# Percona - copy-back option in xtrabackup for restoring partial backups

Tags: mysql, percona, mysql-backup

I use **copy-back option in xtrabackup while doing a full data restore**.
For copy-back option to execute successfully, the **data directory should be empty**.

Why cant I use the same copy-back option while doing a restore of partial backups instead of manually copying the 'tablename'.* files to the data directory?
May I know the limitations of copy-back option and why cant I use it for partial backups as **copy-backup** option copies the files from the backup directory to the data directory only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is an option --force-non-empty-directories option which allows to use copy-back option for partial backups.
There are few things to do before.

**Note: We should NOT prepare the backup. Because this create ib_logfiles and restoring these files to the server makes it corrupted.**

1. If we want to restore a particular database while having the remaining data in the server, we need to remove the database directory, ibdata1,xtrabackup_info file(because the data cannot be overwritten with --force-non-empty-directories option).
2. Then we can run the copy-back along with force-non-empty-directories option.
3. Restart the server.
4. The database is restored till the point of backup.